# Universal Sortable Format Specifier for only Date

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetime-format

Just looking through the [Microsot Standard Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) to find universal date format specifier(yyyy-MM-dd). I can see there is one for UniversalSortableDateTimePattern which is "u". and the date outputs as:

```
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'
```

I am only interested in the date part and I don't really want to keep typing custom format  as

```
date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd").
```

Is there any format specifier letter for universal **date** format? Or the only option is custom date format?

Something like **DateTimeFormatInfo.UniversalSortableDatePattern**

Comment: Since it's not in the list your only option to do this without using a custom format is using `"d"` and a specific culture (e.g. `jp-JP` => `yyyy/MM/dd`)

Comment: Best you could get is `var dt = DateTime.Now.ToString("s")` but this gives you T and then the time afterwards so you would either need to use a custom format like you're doing and specify this in a config file if its going over multiple places or if its in just the one class file then specify the format as a read only or const value

Comment: `date.ToString("u").Split(' ')[0]`?

Comment: My aim is to reduce the number of characters I type @ManfredRadlwimmer :)

Comment: @akd Code-Golf or esthetics?

Comment: I'd say both and less typing means less mistake. I had an issue recently and noticed that someone made a typo in the code as 'yyyyy-MM-dd'. when they format the date. I am also not fan of moving those into config file as it would mean updating all the aspx pages etc. I was wondering if there would be a single letter that would do the same custom specifier. but I guess there is not.

Comment: The I'd just define a static class with constant formats e.g. `public const string GlobalDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"` and use that one everywhere, or create an extension method for DateTime that outputs exactly that format.

Comment: This is not also possible when using 2 way binding Text='<%# Bind("StartDate", "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}") %>'. the format string cannot be replaced with constant string. When I use the Eval instead then I get the yyyy-MM-dd in the text box instead of the value. Any idea @ManfredRadlwimmer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155814/discussion-between-akd-and-manfred-radlwimmer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. This format is hardcoded on datetimeformatinfo.cs in mscorlib.

```
internal const String universalSortableDateTimePattern = "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd HH':'mm':'ss'Z'";
```

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs,115

Looks like you don't have too much choice on your case.

Just use;

```
date.ToString("yyyy'-'MM'-'dd")
```

or you can read that format somewhere else like config file etc.

Comment: Its a pity that they haven't hard-coded one for 'yyyy-MM-dd' which is mostly used I believe.

Comment: @akd Sorry but looks like you don't have too much option here.